# How to get MessageProperties with Spring RabbitMQ MessageListener

Tags: java, xml, spring, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm creating a Spring MessageListenerAdapter that is listening to a Queue for XML messages.

This is my amqp configuration:

```
    @Bean()
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                                  MessageListenerAdapter messageListener) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames("queueA", "queueB");
        container.setMessageListener(messageListener);
        container.setChannelTransacted(true);
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter messageListener(Receiver receiver) {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "receiveMessage");
    }
```

Currently the receiving of messages works, but only if the returning type of my listener is `String`.

With following Listener I receive my XML messages, so that's fine. But I'm not able to get the `messageProperties` of the original message:

```
@Component
public class Receiver {

    public void receiveMessage(String message) {
        try {
            if (message.isEmpty()) {
                log.info("---> Received message is empty!");
            } else {
                log.info("---> Received message: <{}>", message);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("---> Exception in processing receiv                                              
                   ed message!", e);
        }
    }                                                                                                                            
}
```

If I change the return type of **receiveMessage()** to `bytes[]` or `Message`, I get the following error message:

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Failed to invoke target method 'receiveMessage' with argument type = [class java.lang.String], value = [{myXmlMessage}]
```

I've already tried MessageConverters, but I'm a newbie with RabbitMQ. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself: By default a MessageConverter is used for the MessageListenerAdapter. To prevent this, the MessageConverter must be set to **null**. Now it works and I receive the plain message with all messageProperties!

```
@Bean
MessageListenerAdapter messageListener(Receiver receiver) {
    MessageListenerAdapter messageListenerAdapter = new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "receiveMessage");
    messageListenerAdapter.setMessageConverter(null);
    return messageListenerAdapter;
}
```